Business central change dataset in Power Apps
I have created a PowerApps solution in my dev environment  which is connected to Business Central Dataset ( Sandbox environment + Company A ).
Now I want to migrate this Power apps solution to production environment that should connect to Business central dataset ( Production environment + Company A ).
How I can achieve that as I am not able to update the app itself because it must be migrated as managed solution. While exporting this as managed solution , there is no popup comes to update the connections.
I also tried editing the connections but there is no option to change the dataset.
Thanks,
Saira.
